# Error al concatenar en el valor por defecto de un parámetro de un método

Tags: php, clase, método, concatenación

Tengo la siguiente clase en *PHP*:

```
class Usuario extends Content {

    //Otras propiedades y métodos.......

    public function controlAccesoUsuarios($redir = SITE_LANG .'login') {
        if (!LOGGED) {
            Url::redir($redir);
        }
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que en *PHP 5.5.38 (de 1&1)* me da el siguiente error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in /homepages/10/dXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/demo/class/Usuario.class.php on line 183
```

Sin embargo funciona sin problemas en un *XAMPP con PHP 5.6.30* y en un servidor *Hostinger con PHP 5.6.21*.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Qué limitaciones de sintaxis hay a la hora de concatenar en el valor predeterminado de un *método/función* y en qué versiones de *PHP* es correcto mi código.

Comment: Probaste en ambos casos que SITE_LANG tenga el valor esperado?

Comment: Es probable que sea problemas de versiones. Una opción es establecer el argumento en `$redir = null` y dentro de la función usar `$redir = (empty($redir))? SITE_LANG .'login' : $redir;`. Esto no debería darte errores con las versiones. Como recomendación, para evitar estas cosas (que son mínimas y tienen fácil solución), desarrolla con una versión similar al del servidor de producción.

Comment: La constante SITE_LANG tiene un valor válido de tipo string, lo he comprobado, por otra parte he cambiado esa constante por `'prueba' . 'login'` y también hay error

Answer (score -1):

Segun el manual:

[Argumentos de funciones](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php)

> El valor predeterminado debe ser una expresión constante, no (por
>   ejemplo) una variable, un miembro de una clase o una llamada a una
>   función.

Aun que no dice explicitamente que no se pueda utilizar la concatenación entiendo que debe ser algo de lo que prescindir a la hora de asignar valores por defecto.

Facilmente puedes solucionar esto de la siguiente forma

```
public function controlAccesoUsuarios($redir = null) {
    if(!$redir) {
        $redir = SITE_LANG .'login';
    }

    if (!LOGGED) {
        Url::redir($redir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como observación, me parece una pésima sugerencia de sobreescribir un valor Booleano con un String. Se pierde toda trazabilidad del código. Es mejor reasignar la concatenacion de la constante y valores a otro valor. Además, de que se puede simplificar mucho esa función. ```<?php
CONST SITE_LANG_LOGIN = SITE_LANG . 'login';

public function controlAccesoUsuarios(bool $redir = false) {
    if (!LOGGED && !$redir) {
        Url::redir(SITE_LANG_LOGIN);
    }
}```

Comment: @manuerumx Fijate que en el ejemplo que pones pierdes la opcion de pasar un valor diferente a `Url::redir` que es una de las cosas que espera poder hacer el OP. Quizas el valor por defecto deberia ser null en lugar de un boleano. Igualmente un saludo.